# My 9 Line of Python code is using 100% of My CPU

Tags: python, cpu-usage

I have a python script (test.py) that need to be restarted every 10 - 15 minutes using below code :

```
import subprocess,time
WAIT=700
file_name = ("test.py")
while True:
    process=subprocess.Popen("python "+ file_name)
    now=time.time()
    while time.time() - now < WAIT:
        pass
    process.kill()
```

But is taking 100% of my CPU . What can be wrong ? if i run test.py only everything is normal .

Comment: You probably meant `> WAIT`.

Answer (score 3):

You should use the `.sleep` function, which won't use a cpu intensive while-loop:

```
import subprocess,time
WAIT=700
file_name = ("test.py")
while True:
    process=subprocess.Popen("python "+ file_name)
    time.sleep(WAIT)
    process.kill()
```

Comment: @trustdeeugochukwu that error has something to do with whatever your `test.py` script does, I can only presume. Please don't post links to images of code (especially hosted on sketchy websites). Code is *text*. Copy and paste it into the *question itself*

Answer (score 0):

The problems comes from this part of the code

```
while time.time() - now < WAIT:
    pass
```

python spent all CPU time to execute this loop as fast as the CPU allows it (so possibly million of time per second).

You need put a sleep the process a before continuing in the loop

```
while time.time() - now < WAIT:
    time.sleep(1)
```

This way the process will sleep 1 second and will execute the loop again, so the CPU will be idling. You can change the 1 to 10, 20 or even `WAIT` if you want to sleep 700 seconds.