# How can i restart a python script using another python script when error occurs

Tags: python

[Here is my Previous question of how to restart every X minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51683493/my-9-line-of-python-code-is-using-100-of-my-cpu)
The previous question is working .  But i want it to restart only when the error occurs .

Below is the current code am using  :

```
import subprocess,time
WAIT=500
file_name = ("bot.py")
while True:
    process=subprocess.Popen("python "+ file_name)
    time.sleep(WAIT)
    process.kill()
```

Comment: Look into `try-except`

Comment: What error? You mean when you have to kill it? Or when the process you ran with `Popen` returns an error code?

Comment: Yes when the process return an error .

Comment: Can you post your original code in this question please? It will help add context for me and anyone else.

Comment: Added Code to question :

Comment: What error do you get exactly? Best to paste that into your question in future. Helps for faster resolution :)

Comment: I have a script that throws error after certain minutes  .  I have tried fixing it  but it seem to be a telegram issue .   I resolved to using the above code to restart the script after X minutes .   But, what i want is to restart **only** when the error occurs and not every X minutes .   I want a way to catch the error and restart the script .

Answer (score 1):

Place your script in a function. Default is four retry ;)

```
import subprocess
import time

def retry_code(n=4):
  '''
  function that attempts to perform a 
  task n times. If fails terminates itself
  '''

  try:

    WAIT=500
    file_name = ("bot.py")
    while True:
        process=subprocess.Popen("python "+ file_name)
        time.sleep(WAIT)
        process.kill()
        raise TimeoutError('Took too long')

  except TimeoutError as e:

    # We need a condition of numbers of attempts
    # Else we will have infinite attempts. And see if process failed

    n-=1  
    if n > 0:
      print('trying again!')
      retry_code(n) # <<-- call function again :)
    else:
      print('failed attempts')
      quit() # terminate
```

Comment: Try this modification. I removed the if process.returncode != 0? We need though to find out if the code was unsuccessful ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to poll the return value from `Popen` and see how if and how it exited. If `.poll() is None`, that means it's not done yet. If it's anything except `0`, that means it failed with an error. `.poll()` will also set the returncode attribute on the `process` if it's finished.

```
import subprocess, time
WAIT = 5
WAIT_LIMIT = 500
file_name = "bot.py"
waited = 0

process = subprocess.Popen(['python', file_name])
while process.poll() is None:
    if process.returncode is None:
        # No return code is set yet, sleep
        time.sleep(WAIT)
        waited += WAIT

        # Not done yet, check if we waited too long
        if waited >= WAIT_LIMIT:
            print 'Killing old one and restarting a new one'
            process.kill()
            process = subprocess.Popen(['python', file_name])
            waited = 0
    elif process.returncode != 0:
        # Return code is non-zero, start over
        print 'Failed with error code, restarting'
        process = subprocess.Popen(['python', file_name])
        waited = 0
    else:
        # Return code is 0, success
        print 'Succeeded with exit code 0'
        break
```

Comment: The entire code snippet works under the assumption that `bot.py` exits with a non-zero exit code when your error happens. Without me seeing what's in `bot.py`, it's kind of hard to help any more than this.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a lot of information. But I think what you will probably end up wanting to use is python's `try, except` handlers. A `try` is a block of code that python will attempt to execute, if an exception occurs the code will jump into the `except` block instead of exiting the programming with an exception message. Here is a basic example:

```
import random
import time

def main():
    print("started main function")
    while True:
        a = random.choice(['a','b','c','1', 2, True, int('5')])
        try:
            print("choice "+a)
            time.sleep(2)
        except Exception as e:
            print("cannot concatenate "+str(type(a)))
            time.sleep(2)
            main()
            break

main()
```

When variable `a` equals something other than a string this code will throw a `TypeError` exception. But instead of exiting the program, python will jump into the `except` block and restart the `main()` function